# how to show continue reading on excerpt in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

On main blog page all excerpt is showing but there is no continue reading and Have coded very well?

on the content.php I have the code

```
<div class="post-excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- post-excerpt -->
```

On function.php I have place this code and the moretag class is not present in my style.css file and not in bootstrap is this is the reason.

```
/**
 * Replaces the excerpt "more" text by a link.
 */
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
    return '... <a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> continue reading &raquo;</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

I expect output on the main blog page every excerpt should have continue reading link and should clickable and show full post.

Comment: I have try out all Previous questions asked here but couldn't  help out.

Comment: on clikcing read more you will be navigated to single post

Comment: yes you are right but there is no reading more showing on every excerpt

Answer (score 0):

after 4 hour of struggle I have found answer to my question yahoooo!!

```
on content.php place this.

    <div class="post-excerpt">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <?php if (!is_home()): ?>
        <div class="continue-reading">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink() ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php
                printf(
                    /* Translators: %s = Name of the current post. */
                    wp_kses( __( 'Continue reading', 'mano-theme' ), array( 'span' => array( 'class' => array() ) ) ),
                    the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">"', '"</span>', false )
                );
            ?>
        </a>
    </div>
    </div><!-- post-excerpt -->

        <?php endif ?>
```

on  function.php place this code.

```
/**
 * Customize the excerpt read-more indicator
 */
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return " …";
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

On style.css paste this code

```
.continue-reading {
    text-align: center;
}

.continue-reading a,
.entry-content .continue-reading a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em auto;
    padding: 1em 2em;
    font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

.continue-reading a:hover,
.continue-reading a:focus,
.entry-content .continue-reading a:hover,
.entry-content .continue-reading a:focus {
    border-color: #000;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.continue-reading a::after {
    content: "…"
}
.continue-reading::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 7em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    margin: 4em auto 0;
}

.entry-content .continue-reading::after {
    display: none;
}
```

OUTPUT:

[image]